# Выполнить код через 10 секунд

Tags: android

Как выполнить какой-то кусок кода через определенное количество секунд? В частности хочу метод, который выводит межстраничную рекламу отобразить через 10 секунд, после открытия активити.

Answer (score 3):

Не пишите велосипеды пожалуйста

Все уже за вас придумали

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {...}, 10000);
```

Comment: Имейте ввиду, в этом случае будет создан отдельный поток, в котором выполнится код. То есть, к примеру, обращаться к UI элементам оттуда напрямую нельзя.

Comment: Все таки вариант через `Handler` более предпочтительный (для Android конечно)

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вариант:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {...}, 10000);
```

Выполнить тоже самое в MainThread(UIThread) из любого background потока:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {...}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
 class Retarder implements Runnable {
        private long retard;
        public Retarder(long retard) {
            this.retard=retard;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(retard);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Interrupted retard");
            }
            //выполняем код здесь
        }
    }
```

Вызываем так:

```
new Thread(new Retarder(10000)).start();
```

Comment: Почему нельзя было использовать стандартную реализацию?

new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {...}, 10000);

Comment: Вариантов миллион и маленькая тележка сверху, я как бы применил олдскульный вариант :)

Comment: @mifkamaz почему вы решили, что именно ваша реализация стандартная? Это просто один из способов, который не подойдёт для всех случаев. ```Timer``` создаёт новый background поток, в котором будет выполняться ```TimerTask```. Таким образом в нем нельзя обращаться с UI элементами напрямую. Так что вы поторопились назвать этот метод стандартным.

Comment: Ну в общем-то, да)) На вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные