# Как дождаться Ripple эффекта кнопки?

Tags: android

Как дождаться Ripple эффекта кнопки?

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку то открывается новое окно и анимацию я не вижу. Есть ли параметр который бы говорил. View жди пока анимация не пройдет, а после делай aciton.

Конечно программно это можно делать но сколько же кода уйдет на все это. Страшно подумать

Comment: Поставьте [задержку в выполнении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/670115/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-10-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4/670152#670152) вашего action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете выполнять переход на другое окно с задержкой во времени, чтобы анимация успела показаться.

```
buttonWithRipple.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //..переход на другое Activity..//
            }
        }, 1000); // количество миллисекунд, после которого действие совершится
    }
});
```

С Retrolambda гораздо короче, если боитесь большого количества кода:

```
buttonWithRipple.setOnClickListener(view -> view.postDelayed(() -> {
    //..переход на другое Activity..//
}, 1000));
```

Comment: Хотите сказать Google Тоже так делает? или может есть какая уже готовая реализация для XML?

Comment: На самом деле, Google костылит не меньше чем мы с вами. Посмотрите в документации, я такого способа не знаю, и думаю, что его нет. По крайней мере для API меньше 21го. У Google есть проекты с открытым исходным кодом, можете посмотреть.

Comment: А почему они не могут добавить параметр в xml типо delay. В Гитхабе есть Material Ripple и там куча параметров и все работают на апи 11 и выше.

Можете хотя бы вы объяснить там дибилы работают или они просто леняться что - то нормально делать? Вон слава небесам спустя 100 лет они добавили Font чтобы через xml можно было менять.

Comment: Так пойдите к ним на работу, да сделайте все как считаете нужным)

Comment: Там индузы одни. Я их не пойму)